# openmms Tutorials python3.7.9 laspy error

Tags: python, attributeerror

During the OPENMMS tutorial, we are unable to proceed due to the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

  File "C:\OpenMMS\code\openmms_georeference_livox.py", line 1416, in georenter code hereefChunk_livox
    timeMin, timeMax, logMessStr = outputPrcsPoints_l_verbose(lock,filePath,chunkFileName,X,Y,Z,points_timing,points_intens,points_dist,points_azi,points_vert,R,P,H,Xg,Yg,Zg,Lat,Lon,Xg_offset,Yg_offset,Zg_offset)

  File "C:\OpenMMS\code\openmms_georeference_livox.py", line 1072, in outputPrcsPoints_l_verbose
    hdr = laspy.header.Header()
AttributeError: module 'laspy.header' has no attribute 'Header'
```

Why does this error occur?

Comment: laspy version error,  i use laspy 2.0.1  change 1.7.0 and fixed

Answer (score 1):

Changing laspy version to 1.7.0 (from 2.x) will fix it.